# An equation to represent all vector solutions to a system of equations with infinite solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

If both $x$ and $y$ are solutions to a system of linear equations with infinite solutions then

$$z = αx + (1 −α)y$$ is also a solution for any real α.

---

I'm having some trouble understanding this. Can you explain how this is derived and also its intuition?

I understand that multiplying for example $x$ by a scalar usually necessitates a change in $y$ for $z$ to be a solution, but how do we know that scalar is $1-α$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x$ be a solution to $Ax=b$ and let $y$ be a solution too, i.e. $Ay=b$. Testing $z=\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y$
$$
Az=A(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)=\alpha Ax+(1-\alpha)Ay=\alpha b+(1-\alpha)b=
(\alpha+1-\alpha)b=b.
$$
Thus $z$ is a solution too.

**Intuition:** all solutions to $Ax=b$ span a linear manifold, think a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The condition $z=\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y$ is a parameter equation for a line through points $x$ and $y$. Clearly if $x$ and $y$ are *on* the plane, then the whole line through them (any $z$ on the line) is also on the plane.

Comment: But then there are no infinite solutions as $x=y$ meaning only ONE solution. You can only write this if $\det(A) = 0$, for if not, then $x=y$ and $z=y$.

Comment: @johannesvalks I do not understand how you conclude "but then $x=y$". What makes you think so? *If* the solution is unique then yes, $x=y$, and the space of solutions is a point as well as the "line" $z$ shrinks to the point. This is a special case. In order to get an intuition it is worth to consider a general case.

Comment: If $Ax=b$ and $Ay=b$ and $A^{-1}$ exists, then $x = A^{-1} b$ and $y = A^{-1} b$ so $x=y$ and thus $x=y=z$.

Comment: anyhow, I like your method so +1.

Comment: @johannesvalks Yes, it can happen, still the same argument works. It can even be no solutions, that is, $x,y\in\emptyset$ and the "line" $z$ is empty set. However, it is better to develop a geometrical picture first on a general case.

Comment: It is a small condition to ensure that there exists many solution, nevertheless +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a system of equations

$$ \mathbf{Ax} = \mathbf{b}$$

and assume furthermore that $\mathbf{x_1}, \mathbf{x_2}$ solve this system.

Then clearly $$\mathbf{A} (\alpha \mathbf{x_1} + (1- \alpha) \mathbf{x_2}) = \alpha \mathbf{b} + (1- \alpha) \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{b}.$$

Answer (score 0):

What is the definition you have of a linear equation or a system of linear equations? That may sound a daft question, but we normally mean by this that the linear operator/system $L$ satisfies $L(\alpha x+\beta y)=\alpha L(x)+\beta L(y)$

Equivalently this can be written as $L(x+y)=L(x)+L(y)$ and $L(\lambda x)=\lambda L(x)$

Either way the $\alpha, \beta, \lambda$ are simply scalars, and the $x, y$ are variables or vectors (or elements of some other kind). These properties of $L$ are what we mean by a system being linear.

If you have $L(x)=L(y)$ then $L(\alpha x+(1-\alpha y))=\alpha L(x)+(1-\alpha)L(y)$ by the linearity property. Then put $L(y)=L(x)$ to get $L(x)$ on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

If the system of equations is written as

> $$
> \mathbf{A} x_k = b
> $$

then the system can only have infinite solutions, IF $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ does not exist, as otherwise we would have

> $$
> x_k = \mathbf{A}^{-1} b,
> $$

having only one solution as $x_k = x_\ell$.

Considering $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ does not exists, we get

> $$
> \mathbf{A} \Big[ \alpha x + (1-\alpha) y \Big] = \alpha \mathbf{A} x + \mathbf{A} y - \alpha \mathbf{A} y = \alpha b + b - \alpha b = b,
> $$

whence

> $$
> \alpha x + (1-\alpha) y
> $$

is also a solution.

Comment: A minor comment: one talks about determinants only for square matrices, however, the system $Ax=b$ does not have to be square.

Comment: You are absolutely correct!! I corrected it... Thanks for the comment!!!